# Flutter | How to fill the remaining space of a ListView?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, I have a ListView:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 100
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),

              // How to make this container fill up the remaining height?
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This produces the following view:

[image]

**Question:** How can I make the second box (with black background color) fill up the remaining space? If the content of the box exceeds the remaining space, the ScrollView will enable scrolling.

Is this possible?

Comment: So there are going to be just 2 container in your listview ? If I guess correctly you want to scroll yellow container if the black container exceeds the space right?

Comment: It would be better if you can elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve here. To answer your question: yes, its possible, but u need to give a height to your container . Answer provided by `Kdon` and `Ravindra` seems fine, you may try it out

Answer (score 11):

There is a better option here using [SliverFillRemaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) in combination with [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) instead of a `ListView`

in your case the code will look like this.

```
Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            shrinkWrap: true, // or false 
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child:Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 100
              ),),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: SizedBox(height: 10),),

              // use SliverFillRemaining to make this container fill up the remaining height?
            SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: false, // if using a column, so the widgets in it, doesn't scroll
            child:Container( //this container will fill the remaining space in the ViewPort
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )  ,
            
            ],
          ),          
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  Sometimes scrolling to the bottom comment with no upvotes has rewards haha.

I've been wanting to get a spacer at the bottom of a ListView that sticks to the bottom of the screen if there are not enough list elements.  All solutions I found involved like, media queries and I knew there had to be an easier way.  And this seems more efficient with sliver lists and no shrink wrapping.

Comment: this solution works only if we want to fill the last remaining space, is there a solution if we want to fill the space between all the silvers ? thank you !

Comment: @MohamedBENKHOUYA i think you use Spacer() for that. in this case you have to wrap it in SliverToBoxAdapter().

Answer (score 4):

*Fill the remaining space of a ListView* means filling the infinite height. I will prefer using `Stack` as body in this case, hope you can simply archive this.

**How can we do without stack?**

In this case, we can get the height and use it on `Column` and using `Expanded` on inner child that will fill the remaining spaces even for dynamic height.

I prefer using [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get height.

```dart
 body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    // 1st child of listView
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 100),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
```

Comment: yes but then if it does not fit, it would not be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You can get size and then set a proportion for each...
And set NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to ensure no slight scrolling, as per below this appears to get what you are seeking.

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: _size.height * 0.20),
              SizedBox(height: _size.height * 0.10),              // How to make this container fill up the remaining height?
              Container(
                height: _size.height * 0.70,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. use MediaQuery [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html). add MediaQuery height to your black container

Refer blog also [here](https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6) for **relative to screen size**

```
     Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),

                // How to make this container fill up the remaining height?
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]